# Error handling for popen

Tags: php, windows

I am using popen in PHP to execute a TCL file .

```
     $cmd='C:/wamp/www/Tcl/bin/tclsh84.exe';  //windows
             $ph = popen($cmd,'w')
```

But if someone restarts the machine or the tclsh84.exe process is killed . How do I know this error condition has occured ? 
 $ph is not returning 0 in these conditions.

Regards,
Mithun

Answer (score -1):

you see the documentation of the tasklist utility from [there](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx). This utility is a kind of task manager in command line (a bit less feature since you can only list process and not affect them). Having that utility accessible on your server, you can use [exec](http://fr.php.net/exec) function to get list of process and work with that.

a probable code would be something like that:

```
 function isTCLRunning(){
   $running = false;
   exec('tasklist.exe /fo CSV /fi tclsh84.exe', $output);

   return count($output) == 1
  }
```

*note:* this is completly untested you might want to play a bit with tasklist and make sure it is returning expected output before starting to code your PHP function.

Comment: Maybe because the original question was really about popen(), and your answer is about tcl (which is really an incidental detail in the original question).